# WPF C# SelectAll в СheckEdit

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding

Как сделать `checkEdit` selectAll ?

Xaml Где автоматически генерируеться `checkEdit`

```
   <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding MyProperty, Mode=TwoWay}" Margin="0"  Grid.Column="1" Grid.RowSpan="1" x:Name="MyCheck" >
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <dxe:CheckEdit Content="{Binding FilePath, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Padding="2.5" Margin="3"  
                               IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapPanel Orientation="Vertical"  />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    </ItemsControl>


        <Button x:Name="filtrButton" Content="Filtr" Command="{Binding FiltrCommand}"  Padding="5" Margin="3" IsEnabled="{Binding IsEnabled}"/>

        <dxe:CheckEdit x:Name="CheckALL" Content="Select All" Padding="2.5" Margin="3" IsChecked="{Binding AllSelected}" />
```

C#

```
        private bool? _allSelected = true;
    public bool? AllSelected
    {
        get { return _allSelected; }
        set
        {
            _allSelected = value;

          MyProperty.ForEach(x => x.IsChecked = value);

            OnPropertyChange("AllSelected");
        }
    }
    public List<MyCheckBox> MyProperty
    {
        get { return TempList; }
        set
        {
            TempList = value;
            OnPropertyChange("MyProperty");
        }
    }
/// добавление название файла и его select
        TempList = new List<MyCheckBox>();

        foreach (var type in tempUniqueList)
        {
            TempList.Add(new MyCheckBox(type, _allSelected));
        }

        MyProperty = TempList;
```

Помогите исправить

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте заменить

```
public List<MyCheckBox> MyProperty
```

На

```
public ObservableCollection<MyCheckBox> MyProperty
```

Дело в том, что List-ы нелучшие друзья вам, когда речь идёт о WPF биндингах. Можете провести эксперимент - Поставить Breakpoint на set-блок вашего списка и через UI добавить в список элементы и удалить пару тройку. Breakpoint не отработает, потому что по факту вы меняете не сам MyProperty, а его элементы, хотя биндитесь действительно к нему. Поэтому, вам нужно, что-бы при изменении , хранимых в MyProperty, объектов у вас вызывалось OnPropertyChange("MyProperty"); - ObservableCollection сделает это за вас.
Класс ObservableCollection унаследован от базового класса Collection, который может применяться для создания специальных коллекций; он использует внутри себя List. Методы базового класса SetItem() и RemoveItem() переопределены для инициации события CollectionChanged. Клиенты этого класса могут регистрироваться на это событие, используя интерфейс INotifyCollectionChanged.
Думаю, это то, что вам нужно

Comment: без изминений, данные есть что произошла смена с true на false, но оно не меняет в самой програме, тоесть не показывает произошла смена или нет

Comment: "произошла смена с true на false" смена какого (каких) значений?

Кстати, вот этот кусочек кода 
`TempList = new List<MyCheckBox>();

        foreach (var type in tempUniqueList)
        {
            TempList.Add(new MyCheckBox(type, _allSelected));
        }

        MyProperty = TempList;`

Он из какого-то метода или конструктора? Мне кажется, что у вас инициализация происходит некорректно

Comment: этот кусок кода,  с конструктора, произошла смена `_allSelected` но в самой програме этого не видно

Comment: Хотелось бы увидеть код класса MyCheckBox. там у свойства IsChecked вызывается OnPropertyChanged?

Comment: Кстати, вот эта строчка
MyProperty = TempList;
Не имеет вообще никакого смысла, если руководствоваться тем, что есть, потому что внутри вашего класса MyProperty и TempList это одно и то же. Я так понимаю, это сделано для того, что-бы как-раз таки отработал OnPropertyChanged при первом запуске? Если так, то правильнее сделать это так -
        `MyProperty = new List<MyCheckBox>();

        foreach (var type in tempUniqueList)
        {
            MyProperty.Add(new MyCheckBox(type, _allSelected));
        }`