# Перерисовка List<T> на странице Page с использованием ViewModel xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, viewmodel

Товарищи, подскажите пожалуйста в следующем вопросе, во ViewModel есть параметр простого типа int **TotalSumm**, его понятно как перерисовать на странице, использовав событие PropertyChangedEventHandler, но в этом ViewModel есть еще класс **korzinaModel**, в котором содержится список List, каким образом его можно перерисовывать на странице, когда пользователь в Page1 выбирает товары, а на Page2 должны выводиться выбранные им товары, Page2 что то вроде корзины, и один ViewModel ипользуется для обоих Page?

Код ViewModel

```
public class KorzinaViewModel: BaseViewModel
{
    public IKorzinaModel korzinaModel;


    private ItemLPH _selectedItem;//Храним выбраный итем
    public ItemLPH SelectItem// Биндинг события клика добавления в корзину
    {
        get
        {                
            return _selectedItem;
        }
        set
        {
            _selectedItem = value;

            if (_selectedItem == null)  return;

            // заносим в корзину выбранный товар
            korzinaModel.AddItem(_selectedItem);
            NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(TotalSumm));// обновляем(перерисовываем) общую сумму покупки

            NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(korzinaModel));//?? как перерисовать класс, в котором хранится список (korzinaModel.ItemsBuy)

            _selectedItem = null;
        }
    }


    public string TotalSumm
    {
        get
        {
            return "Сумма "+korzinaModel.TotalSum.ToString()+" руб.";
        }
    }


    public KorzinaViewModel()//конструктор
    {
        this.korzinaModel = new KorzinaModel();
    }


}
```

ХAML Page1 и Page2 идентичны

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="App5.Views.KorzinaPage">

<StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">

    <ListView x:Name="MyListViewKorzina"           
        ItemTapped="ItemTapped"
          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectItemDel}"   
          HasUnevenRows="True"
          >
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Image Source="{Binding ImageName}" WidthRequest="100" HeightRequest="70" />
                    <StackLayout>
                        <Label Text="{Binding Name}" FontSize="12" />
                        <Label Text="{Binding CountOneitem}" FontSize="7"/>
                        <Label Text="{Binding Rub}" FontSize="10"/>
                    </StackLayout>
                </StackLayout>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>

</ListView>
    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Label Text="{Binding TotalSumm}" HorizontalTextAlignment="Start"/>

    </StackLayout>
</StackLayout>
```

Каким образом можно так же перерисовать данные ниже которые берутся из списка

```
<Image Source="{Binding ImageName}" WidthRequest="100" HeightRequest="70" />
                <StackLayout>
                    <Label Text="{Binding Name}" FontSize="12" />
                    <Label Text="{Binding CountOneitem}" FontSize="7"/>
                    <Label Text="{Binding Rub}" FontSize="10"/>
                </StackLayout>
```

Comment: [1](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/546503/220553), [2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/670552/220553), [3](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/719357/220553), [4](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/443461/220553).

Comment: Точно, хотел из листа в ObservableCollection<T> данные перевести да забыл, и не совсем понимал его отличия, все заработало, спасибо)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если необходимо уведомить view о изменениях в коллекции, будь то список товаров и прочее, то лучше использовать не List<T>, а [ObservableCollection<T>](https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/4.13.php), которая сама оповестит View о изменениях.

Comment: Точно, хотел из листа в ObservableCollection<T> данные перевести да забыл, и не совсем понимал его отличия, все заработало, спасибо)